# [GitLab]Use username and password in all projects

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab

I have a few Python Projects on GitLab.com. I want to upload a new Version to PyPI when I create a tag. Uploading to PyPI Needs Username and Password in a CI Variable. Can I set Username and Password for all Projects at once or have I to set it in all my projects per Hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use group-level variables if the projects are all grouped in one group. If not you have to set the variables in all projects one-by-one.

For more information see: https://gitlab.sickcn.net/help/ci/variables/README#group-level-environment-variables